# how to synchronize read and write

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try 
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = RunPreUp("script");
        }
        catch(exception p) { }
 }
```

My problem is RunPreUP("script") take more than 3 minutes so i want to synchronize the write and read for richTextBox1 from RunPreUp("script");
there is  async/await but it's for farmework4.5 and I work on VS2010 framework.3.5.
beast regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate thread?

I have tested this and it works.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread _thread = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunPreUp);

        _thread = new Thread(pts);

        _thread.Start("script");
    }

    private void RunPreUp(object param)
    {
        string parameter = param as string;

        // do work.

        string result = "here is a result";

        richTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = result;
        });

        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: want to elaborate on what is better then?  remove it?   your comment is not particularly helpful

Comment: You can remove it. And calling "Abort()" also. Calling "richTextBox1.Invoke()" is enough for proper functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `BackgroundWorker` class, or `ThreadPool` class.  Either one will let you run lengthy operation, upon completion of which you can update `.Text` property with the result.  Remember that you'll need to do `richTextBox1.Invoke` to set the property.